# PingFederate Sample IdP and SP Applications

Tags: installation, pingfederate

I tried setting up PingFederate 7.3.0 on my machine, but I still don't have a license for it.

**Is the license required to run the sample IdP and SP Applications that they provided? Or am I just missing configurations?**

I followed the steps they provided on this link: http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/JIK/Sample+Applications+Installation+and+Setup

But I got a 404 error from the browser when trying to access the site https://localhost:9031/IdpSample

And a console error saying: 
*Invalid Get Request: /IdpSample RemoteAddr:127.0.0.1*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a license for the server to process any transactions. You can open a licensing case from the support section of the website, www.pingidentity.com.